# Php: use data from a join table with mvc

Tags: php, database, model-view-controller

Heya I am novice web dev or actually I am still in education.

I got this situation Where I have 3 tables lets say : Students, Groups and a join table Student_group.

I put my data from Students in the student model and from groups I put its data in the Group Model so I can use it my application. But I store a date in the Student_group table because I need to know when a student changed from a group.

So my question is in which model do I put this date? Do i need to make a new model for the combined tables or do I need to add another attribute to the student model?

Thanks in advance ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends. Will the student be in many groups, or one?

If one (one to one relationship), you can decide where to put it. The column could be in either the `Student` table, or the `Student_group`. In this case, though, it may be advisable to flatten the data and simply add group columns in your `Student` table. You decide that as well - if it seems unnecessary to have a `join` for a one to one relationship (usually it is, not always), then flatten it. In either case, the data should stay in its respective model. That said, you should use the `Student` model if you handle it in the `Student` table.

If many (one to many relationship), I'd advise putting it in the `Student_group` table and leaving it in that model as well.

All in all, the model should be a direct reflection of the data it's representing. You could make some methods inside your `Student` model to make it easier to get the date, for example. However, I'd personally handle that date inside of the proper model, `Student_group`. As mentioned, the model should be a direct representation of the data. Again, though, there's nothing wrong with making things a bit easier by creating some methods that help out the developer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is indeed a one to many realtionship because a student can be in multiple groups, And I also prefer that a model should be direct representation of the data, so I am going to make another Model. Thanks again for the answer

Comment: Any time! Hope it helps.